# html 5 geo location bug in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, geolocation, local-storage

I making a web site using html5 geo localization and local storage, I am using JS, In most browsers all is ok, but I have some problems with Safary:

Here the explanation:

On button click, I want to get user the GEO location, save it in the local storage, and later to retrieve the information and send it to an email. 
I put some alerts to verify the correct function.

Any of you can help me understand why and find the solution?

Thanks for your help

Here the code:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {

    function localitaionGPS(obj){
        var obj;
        function getLocation(){
            if (navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
            }else{
                alert("Votre navigateur ne suporte pas la Geolocalisation :(");
            }
        }   
        function showPosition(position){
            var maPosition = " position : latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + " longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
            if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
                var dateHeure, anne, mois, jour, heure, minute,seconde;
                dateHeure = new Date();
                anne = dateHeure.getFullYear();
                mois = dateHeure.getMonth()+1;
                jour = dateHeure.getDate();
                heure = dateHeure.getHours();
                minutes = dateHeure.getMinutes();
                secondes = dateHeure.getSeconds();
                if (heure < 10){heure = "0"+heure;}
                if (minute < 10){ minute = "0"+minutes;}
                if (secondes < 10){secondes = "0"+secondes;}
                var laDate = jour +"/"+ mois +"/"+ anne +"_"+heure +"h"+ minutes +":" +secondes;
                // to verify the data
                alert (laDate + "_"+ maPosition);   

                localStorage['gpsPosition'+laDate] = laDate+"_espece : "+obj+ "_"+ maPosition;
            }else{
                alert("Votre navigateur ne suporte pas le local storage :(");
            }  
        }
        getLocation();
    }
    var i=0;
    $('.btnGeo').on("click",function () {
        var src = $(this).attr("data-objet");
        localitaionGPS(src);
    })

    //  rest of code to retrieve and errase the local store data.
    $('.getDatos').on("click",function () {
        var datos = []; 
        for(var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
            var strKey = localStorage.key(i);
            var strVal = localStorage.getItem(strKey)+" ; ";
            datos.push(strVal);             
        }
        $('#message').val(datos);
    });
    $('.cleanDatos').on("click",function () {
        localStorage.clear();
    });

});})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling us what your developer toolbar output is, so I'm not quite sure where your error is located.
However..

getCurrentPosition has two callbacks, first one is the successful callback the second is the error callback. If for example geolocation is disabled on the browser or some form of error is thrown from the browser/device backend then the second callback will be called. Try adding the second callback and test it on the device/browser you're having trouble with to receive further information on what is wrong.

Edit:
By the way, there is also a third parameter to getCurrentPosition wich is a object containing a propery that tells the location service when to timeout. This can be usefully if you want to be able to manage the timeout rather than letting the device handle it.

Comment: Thaks Mattias I will follow your suggestions.

the only library I'm using is jquery has. This is It will be a website that has to work offline, so I have referred to use another tool.